# Use a lock Object to synchronize on my member variable

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm studying a more advanced topic in Java which is multithreading topic.

I see a lot of code used a separate object lock `Object lock = new Object();` to synchronize on some of the class data members.

```
package multithreading;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class ProduceConsume {

    private LinkedList<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    private final int LIMIT = 10;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public void produce() throws InterruptedException {
        int value = 0;

        while (true) {

            synchronized (lock) {
                while (queue.size() == LIMIT) {
                    lock.wait();
                }

                queue.add(value++);
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    }

    public void consume() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            synchronized (lock) {
                while (queue.size() == 0) {
                    lock.wait();
                }

                System.out.print("Size is: " + queue.size());
                int value = queue.removeFirst();
                System.out.println("; value is: " + value);

                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    }

}


public class ProducerConsumerWaitNotify {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ProduceConsume object = new ProduceConsume();

        ExecutorService execuor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        execuor.submit(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    object.produce();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ProducerConsumerWaitNotify.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
        execuor.submit(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    object.consume();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ProducerConsumerWaitNotify.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });

        execuor.shutdown();
        execuor.awaitTermination(1000, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }
}
```

Why we shouldn't lock on the LinkedList object itself? this is not the only example I saw using this technique. Is it a good practice?

However I feel that if I have two separate classes for produce and consume and it take the linked list as member for their constructor, I must synchronize on this linked list object, Am I right?

I know that there are classes in `concurrent` package that are thread safe but this is not my question, I am asking on the best practices between two above ways?

Comment: You should use `final` modificator on you lock objects! If you won't, it is possible to make your `lock` reference point to a new object at some point. So it is possible to sinchronize on different monitors - it's like no synchronization at all.

Comment: An important idea, that is buried in the answers below, is that whatever you use for your lock object, it should be `private`.  You never want to give client classes the ability to do their locking on the same object that you use for your locking.  In an ideal world, the client programmer would be smart enough not to do that, but...  Anyway, it reduces the risk that somebody's program will end up in a deadlock or some other bad behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can, because it's a private member of your class and you and only you can lock on that. If you manage it well, then the user can't cause deadlocks just by using an instance of your class. If the field were public then the user could put a lock on that, then there is a chance for deadlocks if you use the same field for synchronization inside the class. That's why we don't put locks on the this pointer either.

However there are several reasons why to use individual objects for locking:

You can name the object like controlLockerObject (for serializing public access), listLockerObject (to serialize access to a list), updateLockerObject (to serialize access for a code region used to update something) etc.

You can declare the object as final, so you can't replace or delete the object used for synchronization accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

> Why we shouldn't lock on the LinkedList object itself?

You can even lock on the LinkedList object and achieve the same synchronization advantages.

> However I feel that if I have two separate classes for produce and
>   consume and it take the linked list as member for their constructor, I
>   must synchronize on this linked list object, Am I right?

I won't say **you must synchronize on linked list** because that is not the only option. We can have both producer and consumer threads to synchronize on any other `singleton` object or some other `static` field of same/different class or as simple as `synchronize(Object.class)/synchronize(String.class) etc`.

> I am asking on the best practices between two above ways?

Regarding the pros and cons of using the `private lock` (the one that you are using), you may want to go through [Java monitor pattern section of Concurrency In Practice](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=EK43StEVfJIC&pg=PA60&dq=The+java+monitor+pattern&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfweaTytvLAhXCkI4KHfA9ClcQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=The%20java%20monitor%20pattern&f=false), the best resource on Java concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

Having an explicit lock object (make it final) is fine and  is good in terms of separation of concerns. It also acts as documentation since one can immediately see that "oh they are doing some locking here, maybe I should too", which can prevent future developers of that code from accidentally bypassing the synchronisation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ProduceConsumerTest {

    private final int poolsize = 10;
    ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> arrayBlockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(poolsize);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ProduceConsumerTest produceConsumerTest = new ProduceConsumerTest();
        Producer producer = produceConsumerTest.new Producer();
        Consumer consumer = produceConsumerTest.new Consumer();
        producer.start();
        consumer.start();
    }

    class Consumer extends Thread{

        @Override
        public void run(){
            Consume();
        }

        public void Consume(){
            while(true){
                synchronized (arrayBlockingQueue) {
                    while(arrayBlockingQueue.size() == 0){
                        try {
                            arrayBlockingQueue.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            arrayBlockingQueue.notify();
                        }
                    }
                    arrayBlockingQueue.poll();
                    arrayBlockingQueue.notify();
                    System.out.println("Consuming：Current size:"+arrayBlockingQueue.size());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Producer extends Thread{

        @Override
        public void run(){
            produce();
        }

        private void produce(){
            while(true){
                synchronized (arrayBlockingQueue) {
                    while(arrayBlockingQueue.size() == poolsize){
                        try {
                            arrayBlockingQueue.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            arrayBlockingQueue.notify();
                        }
                    }
                    arrayBlockingQueue.offer(1);
                    arrayBlockingQueue.notify();
                    System.out.println("Producing, Current Size："+arrayBlockingQueue.size());
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You can lock on the Object `queue`

Comment: I think there are no need to think on the `arrayBlockingQueue` because it is already thread safe. and I know that I could synchronize on the object itself but what is the best practice.